# How do I figure out which library is causing warnings in my React native app? All the warnings stem from LogBoxData.js

Tags: react-native

**Goal:**
To get rid of the warning `new NativeEventEmitter() was called with a non-null argument without the required addListener method`

**expected result:** The console should show me which file/component the warning is occurring in so I can fix the code or update the library I'm using. I don't directly use `NativeEventEmitter()` anywhere in my code so I'm suspecting it is from an outdated library.

**actual result:**: The console just shows the warning occurs in LogBoxData.js without any indication of where the warning is actually occuring

Is there a way to pinpoint which library is causing this warning to upgrade it/send an MR to fix it?

Or should I just blindly upgrade all the dependencies to the latest version and retest the app?

**Note:** I do not want to just suppress the warning and hide it. I want to go to the root cause and fix it

Thanks!

Comment: The warning message should tell you which specific line in LogBoxData.js is causing the warning. That should lead you to a starting point.

Comment: @rsn I'm facing similar issue. Were you able to find a solution for above?